# Not able to download plugins into jenkins after deploying it's war file to weblogic

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, weblogic12c, devops

I have installed Jenkins by deploying its WAR file to weblogic sever. On typing

http://serverURL/jenkins im redirected to Jenkins page 
I did the first steps of creating login , Now when I go to my MANAGE PLUGIN SECTION. Under available tab there were no plugins showing at first.So, I did some research and i fixed it by using Jenkins->Configure Global Security
Click the checkbox for "Use browser for metadata download"
Now under INSTALLED tab there are no plugins installed whatsoever. I tried to check some plugin to install but im getting bunch of error and the plugin are not installing . Please see screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmUEj.png)

Comment: Your server is telling you it can't access some stuff on `http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/`. Maybe it was down. Maybe your server's firewall is blocking this traffic. Try `curl http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/` from the server and see if that works or produces an error.

Comment: sure! I will try that. Thanks